# Does Stack Overflow need to reward edits with +2 points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

If we removed the +2 reputation gain for approved edits would it bring down the levels of nonsense in the edit review queue or would it lead to a problematic reduction in edits (and thus site quality)?

I can't help thinking that on Stack Overflow (where we have a humongous user base), the edit queues are getting filled up with people desperately earning their +2 points and trying to pass off all manner of crap as a suggested edit. I suspect that if we turned off the +2 point gain, only the true edit heroes would persist and I suspect the quality of their work would be much higher than average.

I assume, perhaps incorrectly, that on smaller SE sites the smaller user base demands that incentives are in place for editing. But on SO, do we simply have enough good eggs who are willing to edit that we can kill off the +2?

*Note: I appreciate robo-reviewers are a huge part of the problem. Ideally we need to fix both things - less nonsense into the queues and less robots approving it. This question focusses on the former task.*

Comment: The answer to that question depends on how much good we feel the edit queues are doing improving overall post quality, and how well audits and review bans are thwarting the robo-reviewers.

Comment: I'd argue we "just" need to fix the reviews. Then there can be as much nonsense as someone would like to suggest, but their contributions would be stopped pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes, it would be good riddance.

Comment: @Bart That's entirely true, but we as a community have failed to do so, despite *considerable* effort spent to that end.  For whatever reasons that either isn't being done, or can't be done.

Comment: *And a 1000 voices would cry out in anguish as their only avenue to 1000 points of reputation was cut off.*

Comment: @Martijn Let us hope that their tears don't cloud their vision so much that they cannot find exit door.

Comment: Sigh, not again.  I see plenty of answers getting upvoted that don't actually answer the question.  Can we solve that problem too by removing the rep for an upvote?  Your proposal is of course *way* too crude to address this.  Stop focusing on the percentage of bad reviews, they are greatly outnumbered by good reviews and mistakes are unavoidable.  The glass is well beyond half full.

Comment: The suggested edit queue never seems to be very large, so its more a case of dealing with robo-reviewers. That said, it would be interesting to see if the quality of edits improved once the +2 was removed. It would also be good if moderators/high-rep users could retrospectively reject an edit to undo the +2

Comment: @Servy Yes, we need to fix the _reviewers_ first.  The _reviews_ would be fixed automagically.

Comment: @devnull As I said in my previous comment; I agree with that sentiment, but we've been following it for years, unsuccessfully.  It seems that the site is incapable of fixing reviewers, either because the problem is just that hard, or through a lack of effort.  Since the problem clearly isn't being solved from that angle, spending some time attempting to address bad editors, rather than bad reviewers, is worthwhile.

Comment: @Servy I might be wrong but I feel that bad reviewers outnumber bad editors by a huge margin.

Comment: @devnull Then perhaps fixing the editors is the more manageable task, despite not being the preferable option in an ideal world.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure if anything is done to [fix the editors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250613/mass-updating-of-tag-wikis-with-content-copied) either.  (In the referenced example, the editor gave up because of hitting the rep cap for suggested edits.  Don't think that anything was done to _fix_ the editor.)

Comment: @devnull This exact post is a proposal to fix the editors...

Comment: Offtopic part: What I dislike is minimum length limit. Sometimes I want to fix few letters and I cannot, I need to touch other text or give up.

Comment: Ontopic part: I am nearing 2k limit when no reputation is given anymore. I will see if I continue with edits. Probably yes. But I hate, when post I edited is deleted. This reduces my will to edit posts. I tend to skip questions with negative score, as it would be loss of time. Btw can somebody build a query to compare number of edits by 2k users and <2k users?

Comment: I agree with @devnull that the *reviewers* are more of a problem. Bad reviewers both accept bad edits and reject good ones. An example of the latter would be [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4153466), which was rejected apparently because it looked like an audit (I asked on meta chat).

Comment: My biggest problem with reviewing edits (I'm thinking about edits that I would ultimately reject) is that by the time I read through the whole thing and decide that the edit is invalid and click reject, the edit has already been approved!

Comment: Yes, some kind of lock is missing for edit/approve. If somebody starts this operation, it is locked for him for 5 minutes and nobody else can start it parallely. It is waste of time when multiple persons do the same task.

Comment: There is no need for +2 for edits for <2K users.  The only rationale I can think of is to allow a new user an avenue to get to be an established user quicker.  Other than that, it just feels weird as a >2K user that I once got rewarded for correcting poor indentation, grammar, and all those lower case i occurrences.

Comment: How about requiring some decent reputation for suggesting edits? Right now it can be done by anyone, I think; adding it as a privilege at, say, 250 or 500 reputation might cut down on low-quality edits and people who just want easy reputation (because at 500 non-edit reputation, they'll already have proven themselves capable of earning it with good questions or answers).

Comment: I think the +2 greatly contributes to the fact that within minutes the majority of posts on SO are well structured, easy to follow, well indented, grammatically correct and pretty decent looking.

Comment: @LeosLiterak What I don't like is that spaces don't count towards the 6 character requirement.  I've made 100 lines of incomprehensible code comprehensible by inserting appropriate indentation, and the edit gets rejected unless I add 6 unnecessary printing characters somehow.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Anecdotally, I don't think I edit less now that I'm over 2k.  However, I never got any substantial proportion of my rep from edits.  It may be different for people who edit for rep.

Comment: @WarrenDew I'm sure that 6 character rule bites occasionally, but I've *rarely* seen a question that requires significant re-indenting that didn't also have a questionable title or some poor grammar.

Comment: I never got points for editing or very few. I find I edit/review more now since crossing the 5000 threshold than I ever did before.

Comment: take a look at [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1978142/kevinabelita)'s rep. Go through the _edits_ he/she has made; I'd have rejected 75% of them as "too minor".

Comment: I doubt i would edit as often as i do (a couple questions every day) if not for the +2.

Comment: lol, i am SO dim. i had no clue about the +2 points for reviews on answers. it now all makes sense. i constantly see many of my answers *corrected* with the addition of some small gramatical tweaks (many of which remove the personality injection that was the intention of the misused grammer in the first place). kerching - still revelling in this lightbulb that's just lit above me - :-)

Comment: The overall quality of the site is far more important than reputation control. +2 points is a small reward for something that is sorely needed.

Answer (score 324):

Based on my very limited experience in reviewing edits on SO, I would say that the absolute majority of suggested edits are legitimate ones.  Just fixing source code formatting and indentation or making tables look like tables does a lot for improving question readability.

I do not mind rewarding people for such efforts.

It would be helpful, though, to be able to remove editing privileges from serial abusers of the system.

Comment: remove editing privileges - nice idea

Comment: Could you post it as feature request question? I do not know how deeply SO developers monitor these discussions.

Comment: Do mods have any sort of mechanism / reports available to them to see whose edits are constantly rejected? I often find when editing that there are serial offenders making lots of minor changes that aren't very good, a short message to such people with the threat of a ban might help.

Comment: I'm not a reviewer or moderator, but it sounds like the system itself is somewhat to blame. There are far more incentives for editing and approving edits than there are for bad edits and approving them. Almost like telemarketers randomly dialing phone numbers... "if I try enough times I'll score some points." If there were a penalty (negative reputation) for abusive actions rather than just "not getting" additional reputation, it seems like it might cut down on the undesirable activity. I guess the hard part is deciding what is "abusive".

Comment: Instead of removing edit privileges alltogether, it might already be sufficient to place very strict rep limits to those abusers.

Comment: Something like "Appreciate Edit" or "Upvote Edit" instaed of rewarding edit directly would be good .

Comment: @PhilDD - After I made my suggestion I started thinking how can it be practically implemented.  One of the ideas was to have the exact reputation value necessary for the privilege to become a property of an individual account. This way it can be raised on an individual basis. However, no matter what approach is taken, this will necessitate an appeal/review process of its own. Ages old dilemma: "Who will police the police itself?" and how many layers is enough.

Comment: I find it somewhat amusing that this answer itself has been edited.

Comment: I thought you **were** banned from editing if your reviews failed enough times?

Comment: "absolute majority of suggested edits are legitimate ones" this doesn't prove anything in regards to the effect of the incentive.  The question is not about the majority of legitimate edits, but the edits which are incorrect no matter how many there are.  What you should be asking yourself are two things: If you eliminate the incentive, will there still be enough people providing good edits?  If you eliminate the incentive, will that decrease the number of bad edits?

Comment: @AaronLS - My answer was mostly about what to consider a "good" edit.  If someone takes time even to reformat code (just click in **{}**) this alone is a useful edit. I also expressed an opinion that the problem of "bad" edits may be exaggerated while basing this opinion on my personal experience.

Comment: @PM77-1 So you're saying this is neither a yes or no to the actual question of "Does Stack Overflow need to reward edits with +2 points?"

Comment: @AaronLS - I'm saying: the system is working - so leave it alone.  I also suggested to neuter serial abusers in some manner to improve  safeguarding of the system. Does it elevate your concerns?

Answer (score 123):

As one of the users whose reputation is primarily derived from edits, I don't much care about the reputation *with one exception:* It would be nice to get to the privilege level that no longer sends things to the edit queue. My predominant contribution to SO as a whole is *making things readable.*

I don't know whether the majority of the edit-derived rep users are similar or not, but when I cap out (far in the future) of edit-rep, I will continue to make edits because I like readable posts and readable code.

`"code blocks" like this bug me`

```cs
    soDoAll()
{
theCodeBlocks();
like(this);
}
// and the code with the wrong prettyprint language
```

That's why ***I*** make edits.

Comment: +1 for an interesting viewpoint. Although the current system wouldn't allow you to avoid the edit queue without earning 1k of "normal" reputation on the site. (2k required to edit without censor, 1k cap on suggested edit reputation).

Comment: @Duncan: I have noticed. ;^) I think it is reasonable in one sense: The community might not be well served by edit-only participants running around with full edit powers and no oversight. On the other hand, +2 with a cap is nice way to jump start (however slowly) users like me towards the point where we're not bugging mods to review usability edits without throwing more than 1k to the rep-crazed edit posse.

Comment: I have this pattern.

Comment: Then you're clearly the exception to the rule, and that's great. But I have seen one user just yesterday that is a perfect example for the OP's question. Tons of minorish edits, next to no other contrib. That's not to say that editing is unnecessary,  but I rejected two such "edits" from this guy in a row, which made me look at his profile.

Comment: On the other side, the privilege to edit without review can be questioned itself. For example, [the latest edit here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1391976/revisions) decreased the question quality and clarity. May be it would have been rejected if subjected to review, may be not, considering to amount of reviewers who accept everything.

Comment: Take the 100th vote for your awesome effort making question readable. Those "code blocks" are really damn irritating.

Answer (score 72):

I think the most annoying part about bad edits (and bad reviews approving them), is that there's hardly anything you can do about them when you see it happening.

Right now, you have the following options:

- Reject the edit, assuming you got there on time and don't get the red bar of death. That's often useless as a horde of robo reviewers are waiting in line to approve it.
- Improving the edit a little just so you can deny the reputation from the one who suggested it (unmark `Suggested edit was helpful` checkbox) - awesome way, but if you take more than 2 seconds, the above horde it already upon you
- flagging the post itself and asking a moderator to check the edit

That's pretty much it, problem is - none of these methods work. The first 2 can't get you there fast enough, and the edits usually get approved. The last seems like overstressing our precious mods time.

Hence, my suggestion is to remove the timing factor - if you arrive late and see an edit already approved, you should have a way to **dispute** the edit review outcome. The details can be further discussed, but the bottom line is that the perpetrator loses the +2 he gained (think of it as a downvote), and the reviewers get gently notified.

To avoid personal vendettas, we can limit the right to dispute edits to one per day per specific user.

Answer (score 22):

> I suspect that if we turned off the +2 point gain, only the true edit heroes would persist and I suspect the quality of their work would be much higher than average.

I suspect you're *partially* right—it would reduce somewhat the number of edits suggested.

But let's do a little sanity-checking here... All of this data is available in SEDE, so I decided to break down the folks who edited during the past year according to the number of edits they suggested—[along with some basic stats on how those edits were received](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201016/suggested-edit-editor-stats-past-year):

```
# Edits   Users  % of all editors % Rejected % Approved 
-------- ------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- 
  1       37,589      51.4            47        53         
  2-  9   26,304      35.9            26.9      73.1       
 10- 99    8,260      11.3            15.6      84.4       
100-499      976       1.3            12.9      87.1       
500-999       67       0.1            12.5      87.5       
 1000+         4       0.0             9.2      90.8
```

Over half of all editors only suggested a single edit. It's doubtful that they're even *aware* of reputation, and if they are they're not getting much from editing. A total of 87% of editors barely earn enough rep to upvote<sup>†</sup>.

There are a relative handful of users who suggest edits *regularly.* It's not hard to imagine that at least a few of them are probably motivated by the potential for earning reputation, and would reduce their editing to some degree (perhaps entirely) if that incentive was removed.

Of course, it's also worth noting that *as a group*, this 1-2% of editors have the highest approval rate. You can speculate on why this is, but I think the answer is clear: they've had plenty of experience, and have learned what sorts of edits get approved.

Which brings us back to the question of [what sorts of edits do we *want?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260194/let-us-bring-an-end-to-the-robo-reviewer-war-phase-1-2/260290#260290)

<sub><sup>†</sup>Trivia: somewhere around 17K votes were cast during the past year by folks who earned the privilege via suggested edits approvals. That's out of 634,799 total upvotes.</sub>

Comment: Of course, the all of the problems with *reviewers* means that just because an edit is approved doesn't mean it's actually a quality edit.  Those editors do learn what gets approved and what doesn't, but they don't necessarily learn what are good edits and what are not.  According to these stats, it also only takes 10 suggestions for users to figure that out.

Comment: There's also the thing of edits getting very repetitive, and if the rep award were removed, some editors would not find it worth their time to edit new posts.

Answer (score 15):

Personal experience...

Early on in my SO career, editing questions was an activity I undertook with grave sobriety.  I used OneLook.com to double check spelling, and grammar experience to correct punctuation.  I considered the 2 points to be a fair exchange for time and effort, and got the 'glow from within' by knowing that someone's chances of getting a great answer were improved by having a grammatically correct question for people to read.

Later in my SO career, I got the menu to approve the edits of others. After inspecting proposed edits for a while I reached the conclusion that some portion of them were contrived and hastily conceived.  Especially worrying were the so-called 'editors' who edited the first sentence only and left the remainder of the text as-is when other edits should have been applied.  Very disappointed that misconceived edits were being immediately approved, the 'glow from within' diminished and finally I stopped participating in that area altogether.  And worse still, I had formed the opinion (and still have the opinion)  that edit/approve was being used by some 'cartels' to game the system.  I now only work the Low Quality Posts, First Posts, and Close Votes queues exclusively.

Net-net.  The 2 points is a fair exchange for time and effort, but ONLY if the suggestion is not a contrivance.  Gaming cartels (if they exist at all) should be stopped by software intervention.  Approvers should be more judicious.  A suggestion that leaves 90% of the text in visible default should be REJECTED.

Comment: There isn't really all that much voting fraud in the suggested edit system.  It's mostly people just accepting everything without reading it *regardless of who submitted the edit*, not just for other accounts of theirs or for friends.  This of course encourages people to submit tons of very minor, or even wrong, edits, knowing that they will largely be approved by people that are either incompetent at reviewing, or just aren't even paying attention to it at all.  (Yes, this is far more depressing than rampant vote fraud.)

Comment: @Servy, thanks for the info about voting fraud.  How do you know that?

Comment: Well, there is some conjecture mixed in there, but it's not wild conjecture, but rather an educated assessment.  Moderators do look for instances of fraud, and do have tools to help them find it.  We see (on a pretty much daily basis) users going around approving edits that vandalize posts, are pure spam, etc. *even when it's generated by the system, and not a real user* (in the case of audits).

Comment: @Servy - in 99% of the cases I can recognize these *audit* edits from the first look. They are never comprehensible.

Comment: @PM77-1 And of course, that's the *goal* of the audit generation system.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between fixing something that is broken and just improving. I think edits that fix broken things, like

- outdated information
- invalid links
- and other obvious question / answer problems

are more valuable than the ones that do minor improvements. I think it would be good if this would be reflected in the reputation reward. Based on the question whether there is a necessity for reward I'd say rewarding helps and the rewarding would work best if there was more than +2 / no points on the scale of rewarding e.g.:

- excellent edit - upvotable like comments (so many points can be gained depending on the votes)
- good edit +2
- crap -1

Comment: Please be careful when you fix "outdated" information that you do not distort the original author's intent.  Factual corrections/critiques should generally be posted as comments, not as modifications of someone else's answer.

Comment: of course the edit should not simply remove the original information. I am thinking more of edits like "as of 2014-04 the most current version of x is y ..." in addition to someone mentioning the most current version 4 years ago ... To look for such changes in the comments would be too much asked for from the reade in my opinion that is why I consider such edits so helpful.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - If the goal is to create the best Q&A site, then surely it makes sense to edit every outdated post, so long as the post's improved by it, regardless of the original author's intent. I'd assume that outdated information should only be retained where it remains relevant.

Comment: If you improve something too much, such edit must be rejected based on the current rules, no matter how valuable it is.  Your own views should be expressed predominantly in *your own* answers and comments.

Answer (score 4):

> If we removed the +2 reputation gain for approved edits would it bring
>   down the levels of nonsense in the edit review queue or would it lead
>   to a problematic reduction in edits (and thus site quality)?

**The sugestion is a wrong approach to me**. It is like an editor say: "Please, stop making questions, since I'll have to edit it".

I my opinion the question quality and the editing quality are always evolving with the community and the only reason there is poor level questions and poor level editing is because the community is **GROWING**.

The growth is something that everything wants. New people, new developers, new questions and the growth is making Stack platform what it is today.

**It sounds more reasonable to me a scale for good editing and bad editing.**

Comment: This isn't the case though.  Bad edits have been a problem ever since editing was introduced.  Nothing about this problem is recent.

Comment: I didn't say it is a new problem. I said it exists because the community grows and the growth is a constant since the beginning.

Comment: This was a problem, and a problem of comparable scale, when the site wasn't growing as much, and hadn't grown as much.  You're specifically claiming that scale is a problem.  I'm saying that there is is significant evidence to the contrary.  This is not a scaling problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of removing the +2 reputation for an approved edit suggestion, what if we added a -1 reputation for making a rejected (not just edited) edit suggestion?  We could even make it +3 and -1.  I know some edits get rejected because I've rejected edits that already had two rejection votes.

Comment: The problem is, most crap reviews get approved by crap reviewers.

Answer (score 4):

On average edits appear to be way more helpful than not. Any solution to the bad edits problem has to not discourage other people from continuing to make edits because overall the edits are bringing a lot of value to the site. The challenge is to align the reputation rewards with increasing the quality of the content. I'm getting the impression that the real issue is with people gaming the edit system for reputation more than people making low quality edits.

If we are worried about people abusing the editing for the purposes of gaining reputation perhaps we can implement a system whereby people can have their edit privileges revoked. I see 2 ways in which this could be done:

1. Temporarily or Permanently ban people from editing if they have a track record of making poor quality edits.
2. Reduce the amount of reputation received for edits if people are on "edit probation"

One of the big issues will be implementing either of these in such a way that it can be done automatically. In either case I think that having some sort of "probation" period after a bunch of low quality edits is a good thing.

My suggestion would be a hybrid of the 2 approaches above:
After making a bunch of bad edits a message telling the user that quality must improve their edits to meet community standards. At this point in time I would imagine that a message telling the user that they should improve their quality of edits in order to not have reputation removed or edit privileges revoked would get the message across to the people who are well intentioned but uninformed. We could the do something like reduce the edit reward to +1 reputation or even change it to 0 until they get some edits of a high enough quality. In all honesty I think this will mostly deal with the issue of people gaming the edit system for reputation.

However if despite this the bad edits continue then I would propose that we can automatically revoke editing privileges entirely for a short amount of time when a user gets some threshold of denied edits. At this point in time it can be made really clear that if bad editing continues their privileges will be revoked. If people get that message but continue making many bad edits then I think a permanent edit ban is in order.

Answer (score 4):

> Does Stack Overflow need to reward edits with +2 points?

Absolutely.

Poor spelling, grammar and formatting are critical factors in someone's initial and continued perception of the quality of Stack Overflow.  Someone who voluntarily takes time out of their day to improve this should be rewarded.

I actually think that the 1000 point limit for edits should be lifted.  Low-quality edits by people just looking to increase their reputation should be filtered out by the peer-review process.  I think the cap should be something more like 1000 points per year for edits.

Yes, I think the need for edits is that bad.

Overall, I think the quality of the site in general is more important than 'reputation control'.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this general sort of behavioru intrinsic to the site?

The whole site is based on two ideas:

1. gamification
2. the score here being a relevant measure indicator of quality for employers

Those two things add up to giving users incentive to find the best way to rack up their scores, and the moderators to structure the point payouts in such a way that the point seeking behaviour turns out to be useful to the broader community.

You see the exact same behaviour with junior-level duplicate questions where people rush to answer them hoping to get the points for the accept plus upvote rather than voting to close the question. Maybe we should remove answering priveleges to people who abuse the system that way too?

The other problem is that is it hard to measure the value of a contribution algorimically. Fixing a single character in a broken URL can be worth much more than a more "substantive" edit character-count-wise.

**tl;dr:** this is a specific example of a problem that applies to all user behaviour on the site, not just what you are suggesting.

Comment: The gamification is there to encourage behaviors *that people aren't doing enough of on their own, without the gamification*.  If people are already doing the given action sufficiently, then there is no need to gamify it.  As to your removing answering privileges (which I recognize was sarcasm), if people actually downvote these very low quality answers (which they should, but don't) then the users *would* end up being answer banned.

Comment: The question asker will get banned but not the answerer trying to game the system but answering low ball duplicate easy questions.

Comment: If the answerer would actually accumulate downvotes for this behavior (currently most users don't downvotes these types of very low quality posts, as I said) and the answer didn't also contribute other quality answers, then yes, they *would* end up being answer banned.  It just doesn't actually happen in practice because people don't downvote these types of answers; in fact they generally upvote them.  This is a sociological problem, not a technological one.  The code solution is already there, the problem is that people's behavior doesn't allow it to do its job.

Comment: @Servy I suspect we are in violent agreement. My point is that most of these issues are cultural/behaviourial.

Comment: @Servy Apparently there is a Meta questio/thread devoted to low-quality quesiton answering: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

The big question is this:  Of the "quality", meaningful edits, how many would not occur if no reputation was given for edits?  My guess is that the vast majority of meaningful edits would still occur if no rep was given.  (I know for my own part that I give rep no consideration when deciding to do an edit -- I do the edit because it clarifies the question.)

On the other hand, how many "nonsense" edits would be eliminated by eliminating the rep bump?  Virtually all of them.  (And I care about this mainly because the nonsense edits create "zombie" questions where one often invests several minutes of study before realizing that it's an old question and likely no longer relevant.  This is very likely a bigger drag on the site than the time invested in reviewing edits.)

Answer (score -5):

Most of the time when I post a question or an answer, it is victim of useless edits, either adding or removing a *"a"* or add/removing *"How to"* in the title (e.g. *"How to write a question?"* becomes *"Write question"*).

Most of the time I revert those nonsense edits, but the editors still get the reputation.

I have yet to see an actual legitimate edit. I believe that edits should be discouraged or forbidden. **The only way I see edits to work properly is if the original author of the edited content is asked to provide approval.**

In case an edit is not approved (i.e. rejected by the original author), then the editor should be fined by the same amount of points that were at stake. So if it's +2 in case of approved edit, they should loose 2 points (-2) if their edit gets rejected. To avoid any risk and show non-interest in the points earning, edits should be able to be "community edit" that would neither add nor remove any of their reputation points.

This is the most optimized system I can think of. If you can't implement it, at least remove the reputation earning to avoid the nonsense useless edits.

Final word, the current review system is totally inefficient, if you check my last question posted yesterday, you would see that an edit was made by an Indian (he removed my "Thank you" at the end of the question) and his edit was approved by another two Indians (what a coincidence!), who could be his friends, or even himself if he runs multiples accounts.

The current edit mechanism is corrupted, time to revoke it.

Comment: Are you referring to *all* edits, or just *suggested* edits?

Comment: ...but I agree: most of [this user's edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2842136/alexender?tab=activity) should have been rejected.

Comment: @Arjan I'm referring to the edits made to my questions/answers for which I was not notified and that I had to discover by myself, only to see that somebody took the time and effort to edit my question just to remove a _"Thank you"_ at the end -_- This happens all the time, some even make edits just to remove a "Hello" at the beginning. Come on, we're still humans.

Comment: I support removing "hello" and "thank you", as it's useless in [a library of high-quality questions and answers](http://stackexchange.com/about). (But to make folks get 2 reputation points for such a minor edit is stupid in my opinion, if only as it takes at least 3 others to approve such an edit.)

Comment: @Arjan - While I understand that it's not "standard", I can't see how a "thank you" at the end of a question in any way decreases the "quality" of the question or the site.  An edit to remove such phrases is simply not justified on its own -- only if the question needs editing for other reasons.

Comment: I don't agree that such minor edits are never justified for people with more than 2k reputation, @HotLicks, as *seeing* people using "thanks" might make new users do the same. (And I wouldn't like to see "thanks" on resources such as MDN or Wikipedia either.) That said, if there's a "thanks" then there's probably more to fix, indeed.

Comment: @Arjan - But there are so many other things that newbies will see that are never corrected.  This site will never be on par with OED for the staidness of it's prose, and it's foolish to make that such a high and mighty goal, vs just optimizing value.