# Ways to improve review queues (both for reviewers and in quality of reviews)

Tags: discussion

In the time since I've gained access to the review queues, I've noticed that all the queues (other than the close votes queue) seem to get emptied out frequently, leaving me with nothing to review. I've also seen some of the discussions (such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252754/does-stack-overflow-need-to-reward-edits-with-2-points)) where people are talking about low-quality reviews.

There seem to be two things happening because of review queues frequently being empty:

- +Things get reviewed quickly because people want to get in their 20 reviews for the day
- -Reviewers spend less time on individual reviews so that they can do as many reviews as possible

If the review queues were never empty, I think we'd still have people who go through their reviews as quickly as possible, but everyone else would not be pressured to review quickly or risk not getting 20 reviews in. However with the close queue, which is far from empty, things are taking forever to get reviewed.

The ideal would be for any reviews to start immediately and for each review to be given the amount of time it needs to be done with high quality. Here are a few ideas that I had for how the current process could potentially get closer to this ideal:

---

1 Have the queues automatically pull up items for waiting users

- Users would click on a review queue, and if there are no items available they would be presented with some sort of waiting message
- When an item is available, it would automatically be brought up

  - Make sure having the queue open in two tabs/pages would not give them more items
  - Give the user an indication that an item is available, perhaps similar to how a gmail tab will indicate when you've received a chat message
- If they are still reviewing an item when another item becomes available for them, they will get it immediately after finishing the current item

  - This individual queue could hold multiple items
  - Items in the individual queue would have a short timeout (a couple minutes, perhaps?) so that a user can't just have a tab open in the background gathering items

---

2 Allow items to be reviewed more times

- Would only happen when we're not behind for a queue
- Somewhat artificially increases the number of items in the queues, but should hopefully give each item a better overall review

---

3 Have a re-review time slot each day (perhaps the last few hours of each day)

- During this time slot you will always have something to review

  - Any items needing review will be handed out first
  - In the absence of items needing review, items that were previously reviewed can be re-reviewed
- I don't know what the best way to handle timezones would be

  - Having a set time doesn't seem too fair to those for whom that would be the middle of their workday or while they usually are asleep.
  - Having the time be relative to local time would probably be easy to get around

    - Then again, the type of person who is likely to take advantage of this might be the type of person who is also likely to give poor reviews just to get through them

---

I'm sure that there are many other possible solutions to this problem, but these are ones that I came up with that shouldn't be too hard to implement but should hopefully have a good impact on the quality of reviews.

Comment: I agree with this completely. Whenever I want to help the site out by reviewing, I feel that I always get a list of 0 available posts (as I don't have 3k rep yet). I wish people could review the posts more than is allowed currently.

Answer (score 3):

I'm all for making the reviews of a higher quality and preventing people from going through them quickly just to get through instead of devoting the time to each item needed to make it a quality review. However, I'm not sure these things will help and here is why

1. I've thought about something similar but if an item is being pulled up for a "waiting user" then others can't see it. What's to say that the user is still waiting. Many members go through the review queue while doing other things during the day and may not be looking at the screen by the time something becomes available. You mention a timeout for this but then wouldn't this make users want to go through them even quicker so they don't miss their window?
2. Unless I misunderstand this, you would want to, at times, raise the number of reviews needed for an action to be taken? This doesn't seem practical or fair. And, if we are only doing this to give people something to do, then we aren't really helping the reviews any.
3. One problem with this is that we have people on here from all different time zones so you may be reviewing things while I'm sleeping. Who's timezone gets to be in this window? My #2 covers the second part of this bullet.

Comment: I am indeed saying we should just give people something to do *when there isn't something else for them to do*. As I mentioned, I think one contributing factor to low-quality reviews is that people want to get their 20 reviews in, so they rush through their reviews. If people knew they did not have to rush, they would give better reviews.

Comment: As for the timezone issue, I did think about that but I don't have a good answer.

Comment: Actually, #2 has been [suggested before for First Posts (and Late Answers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/please-require-more-reviewers-on-first-posts), with very valid reasoning for the change. One person saying a post doesn't need any action is a foolish assumption.

Comment: @animuson I completely agree with that and I've thought in the past that suggested edits should possibly require more than 3, though I'm not sure if it will help with the robo-reviewers. My problem is the reasoning Rob wants this and the implementation. "Would only happen when we're not behind for a queue". If it's going to happen then it should be all the time. Also from the comment, "I am indeed saying we should just give people something to do when there isn't something else for them to do."

Comment: I wasn't aware that first posts and late answers only require one review. So I am in favor of those queues requiring more reviews all the time. I brought up the possibility of it being changeable so that we wouldn't end up will _all_ the queues having a backlog of 10K