# Is editing instead of flagging/closing an issue we need to handle?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, edits

When going through the edit queue, I rather often find questions/answers that have serious problems and should rather be closed/deleted. Yet people edit those to make them look better (mostly formatting, maybe a bit grammar), but don't touch the content at all.

First of all I am wondering why that is the case? I recently read in some meta questions (<strike>sorry, I wasn't able to dig them up anymore</strike> [looks like this is it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252754) ) about the gamification aspects of editing and that some people think it attracts too much "style only" edits that will not really contribute to the content.

Is that an indication of such people? Editing only for +2 rep, not trying to contribute to the overall quality of the content? Don't get me wrong, I think presentation of high quality content is important, but when the content is low quality, polishing it up won't help much (insert reference to mythbusters episode about polishing a turd here).

So is this an issue that we might  need to do something about? Sure, we might have bigger problems but maybe we can do something here.

One idea that I had was that suggested edits to questions/answers lose their +2 after the answer/question has been closed/deleted.

Would that help us?

Comment: Users *do* lose the reputation gained from suggested edits when a post gets deleted.

Comment: @animuson: oh, I was looking for such information but was unable to find it and assumed that this just doesn't happen. Does the same apply for closed questions, or just for deleted posts? Also I wonder if this is then enough, maybe the user should be informed about this so they can learn that they should rather have flagged

Comment: Only deletions. And any user who is paying attention to their reputation and has the "show removed posts" box checked can easily find the exact post which was deleted (although they wouldn't be able to view it).

Comment: At least they're not polishing up obvious spam: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223141/spam-polishing-audits

Comment: @BradLarson: [oh my](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131001135318/walkingdead/images/0/0c/Double_facepalm.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Some people don't *realize* that a question is really that bad and that it should be closed/deleted, even after their edit.  Some people realize it has problems, but don't know how to fix them.  Some people just don't have the discipline to walk away from an unsalvageable question and futility try to improve it anyway.  (I'm guilty of this myself at times, sometimes fixing what you can is just too tempting.)

The most important thing that you can do in this situation is go to the question itself and vote/flag for closure/deletion.  Whatever else you do is rather incidental.

If the edit really does make a substantial improvement to the post, even if the post is still pretty crappy after the edit, you can still generally approve of the edit.  It's moving the post in the right direction, even if it's not pushing it past the finish line.

Comment: It just feels so wrong sometimes, up to the seemingly physical inability to click on approve, on things like "I have this problem too, here is my code" and code format edits...