# (When) should we replace bare URLs with an embedded link and text?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

*** *(Forewarning: all the links in this post are just fake examples with legit markdown.  **No need to click any of them.**  But you can mouse over them to see the example link, if you wish.)*

I see lots of suggested edits where a bare URL like http://www.example.org/ is replaced with text and a link like [Example](http://www.example.org/).

I personally don't find this necessary for simple URLs, and I actually like being able to plainly see where I'm going to be directed to by a link.  I realize that good browsers will assist me in knowing where the link will take me before I click it.  But I don't feel the need to obscure every URL behind link text, particularly if the link text is non-descriptive.

For some longer, more cryptic or minified URLs, it helps if it's replaced with descriptive link text like [example code at ExampleHub](http://www.example.org/unreadable/8fd1a07c85042d0a?a=1&b=2).  But when reviewing edits, I'm very sensitive to whether or not the link text is an improvement over the bare URL.  Sometimes a great URL like http://www.example.org/how-to-do-something gets replaced with a link with poor text like just "[link](http://www.example.org/how-to-do-something)" or "[example.org](http://www.example.org/how-to-do-something)".

There is at least one hi-rep contributor whose intuition for this is dramatically different than my own, in that I see the same user suggesting edits where the only change is to replace a bare URL with link text for its own sake, as if bare URLs were somehow not allowed and *should always* be replaced with a link.  And that was the impetus for writing this post.

I have started to reject some of these edits if the link text is not an improvement over the bare URL.  Because, I do not believe that a link is always better than the bare URL.  I'm also not sure, when I do this, if "Causes Harm" with a comment is an appropriate way to indicate my rejection reason, or if the applicable, but nondescript "no improvement whatsoever" reason is sufficient.

Is there any guidance, official or otherwise, for how to make a call on these URL-to-link edits?

Comment: "good browsers" don't *all* browsers show you the URL when you mouse over a link? Anyway, I would think "no improvement" is better than "causes harm" for a reject reason.

Comment: I personally find links distracting when reading a text, thats why I never paste them directly, but thats a personal preference.

Comment: `I actually like being able to plainly see where I'm going to be directed to by a link` -- Most modern browsers already do this for you.  Hover over [this link](https://example.com); you should see `https://example.com` appear somewhere in your browser window (the lower left hand corner for Chrome).

Comment: In any case, it's certainly not actively harmful to change links like this, and the key word in "no improvement whatsoever" is the word "whatsoever."  I agree that the replacement text should be descriptive, and not merely "link."

Comment: I see no problem doing this, *but fix everything else too!*, There are dozens of suggested edits recently with the comment *"Correctly made out link"* or something similar which only edit the links without fixing the rest of a post.

Comment: @NickA Yes.  Those are the ones that got me thinking about this.

Comment: @Wyck Oh... I somehow missed the last paragraph..., I reject them as no improvement

Comment: "There is at least one high-rep contributor..." Don't know what you consider "high-rep" but above a certain threshhold edits made by "high-rep contributors" do ***not*** land in the Review Queue. Can't remember what the threshhold is, but it's not *that* "high"...

Comment: @CindyMeister I hit it at 2k. OP may be referring to someone who is not in the review queue.

Comment: The best thing I saw concerning this topic was someone editing an explicit "this is just an example and does not work"-URL to hide behind some text....

Comment: I like to use the title of the page when replacing a bare URL with text because, among other things, it's helpful for finding the page again if the link breaks. It's not a frequent problem but it's helped a few times I've had to fix a link.

Comment: Keep in mind that the concept of hovering is a desktop convention and not applicable to mobile.  Hiding the url can often be unwanted in that situation.

Comment: @JBC In that case, you can tap and hold and view the link details, not quite as convenient, but possible

Comment: @TylerH I think Safari desktop by default.

Answer (score 20):

[As a bit of an SO janitor myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252989/241211), I'd say *when it makes sense.* I have a preference for [what I call "Natural linking."](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19935463/revisions) I don't change them every time I see them, but I'd like to make the case below:

### Readability

Full URLs are often long and distract from readability and sentence flow. Prefer linking relevant text.

- No one needs to see `http://` on a web page. The protocol is implied.
- No one needs to see `.php`. They do not care what language your blog is written in.
- *At best,* the path of the URL is moderately readable, if only by virtue of SEO optimisation.

  - Even then, you should be able to concoct natural language that better introduces the link in the context where it appears.
- At worst, the URL is an MSDN link that communicates nothing about what you'll find there.
- Consider that some screenreader and accessibility programs have to read out URLs as `huhtups` `colon` `slashslash` `stackoverflow` `dotcom`…

### Helpful context

Sometimes text needs to be added to replace an inline URL.

- Avoid adding words like "link" and "see here."

  - Some accessibility programs have a sort of link bibliography. It's particularly nice for those if the link text is descriptive, even *absent its sentence context.*
- Instead, prefer to rearrange text to introduce the link.
- In rare cases, it's appropriate to make footnote- or Wikipedia-style links, e.g. [[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388735/241211), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388735/241211), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388735/241211)].

  - This used to help distinguish that there were multiple supporting references before Stack Exchange's CSS underlined links, which didn't display consecutive individually-linked words or phrases were as obviously separate URLs.
  - You can tooltip the footnote-like links for additional context.

### Principle of Least Surprise

A visitor *should not be surprised* by where they go when they click a link, even if they did not hover over it to begin with.

### Don't shirk

Fix the rest of the post, too.

Comment: Great advice. This could also be an answer on [user-experience.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *Avoid adding words like "link" and "see here."* For ages the top search result for "click here" was the download page for Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 11):

From my own experience, the Internet, in general, has been moving towards incorporating links inside descriptive text. Besides my own experience, there are also documented benefits to this approach.

On w3.org there are some success criterion specifically relating to these:

- H30: which states that "the URI of the destination is generally not sufficiently descriptive" and that a good description "lets a user distinguish this link from other links in the Web page and helps the user determine whether to follow the link", more on the [full policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html).
- G53: which covers about the same ground, but provides a few more examples including that the order in which the text appears also matters. IE, it is better for me to link the [full article](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G53.html) after I explained what it contains than on the G53 text in the beginning of this paragraph.
- There's also the more lengthy and texty full success criterion which also explains why this matters for accessibility reasons too, people with motion impairment, cognitive limitations and visual disabilities can benefit from being able to easily distinguish if they want to follow the link or not. When enclosed in text, less keystrokes are needed to parse compared to the full URI, for example. [The criterion](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/link-purpose-in-context.html) really expands on why this is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

I would never replace "example" domain names (like "example.com"<sup>1</sup>) with "user friendly" version - such domains and urls are explicitly designed have no useful content and represent examples of Url/Uri.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Full list of example domain names and suffixes can be found in corresponding [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#page-2)</sub>