# The tag wiki suggested edit review mechanism encourages low quality wiki content

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Related: [Mass updating of tag wikis with content copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250613/168868)

Related *as hell*, in fact, as [someone else is doing the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173495/sann3?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), submitting tag wikis that are unhelpful, barely attributed, useless copy-paste from vendor websites... and sometimes are completely and absolutely totally incorrect, ignoring how the tag is used (like when a project name uses a common noun, the edit will be a definition for the noun instead), ignoring typos, ignoring duplicate tags, etc, etc.

In other words, it's yet another rep grab.

The fact that these edits are being *submitted* is lame enough, but the fact that this *crap* is being let through is a clear and obvious sign that **tag wiki reviewers do not seem to have any idea about what does and does not constitute a usable SO tag wiki!**

Can anything *actually* be done about this?  I mean, who's doing the reviewing here?  I'm getting the feeling that it's those same *low quality* people that are robo-approving normal edits.

Unfortunately tag wikis are special content.  There are actual guidelines and standards to follow.  I can't imagine that the audit system can actually help train people on how to review tag wikis correctly...

Comment: Who's reviewing? ... Slightly high rep (maybe robo) reviewers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

Comment: The best part is that nearly all of their edits are for tags that don't exist, because they were misapplied in the first place and then the posts were edited to remove them. Sadly, IIRC, they won't lose the rep from editing the wikis once the tags are removed from the system.

Answer (score 6):

I think laziness can play a part in robo reviewing tag wikis.

In order to confirm that the edit applies or makes sense, the reviewer has to actually do a little research if they aren't intimately familiar with the tag's subject.

Now, why these reviewers don't just hit the skip button is beyond me, unless it's to bump up reviewer stats...  Maybe the thinking here is (being generous), "Hey, the editor must know what they're talking about..."

One option would be to separate tag wiki edits from regular suggested edits and require a higher rep to approve/reject them.

Comment: Don't tag wiki edits already require higher reputation ([5000, compared to 2000 to approve edits](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))?

Comment: @femtoRgon: You're right--do I hear 7500?  How about 7500?