# Automatic identification of copied wiki content

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Usually, a copied wiki is pretty easy to spot. [Sabre](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4872368) was edited recently and the text just screamed "copied" to me. It took 10 seconds to copy/paste into google and find the source. The wiki edit was approved 3:2. Kudos to user Popnoodles for backing me up on the rejection.

The community frequently raises concerns about wiki edits with significant amounts of copied content appearing in or passing through review:

- [Is there any way to flag a tag, and is there any action taken for a user who repeatedly copies content from external sites to tag wikis?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309314/is-there-any-way-to-flag-a-tag-and-is-there-any-action-taken-for-a-user-who-rep/319396#319396)
- [How to deal with plagiarized content in tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256436/how-to-deal-with-plagiarized-content-in-tag-wikis)
- [Mass updating of tag wikis with content copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250613/mass-updating-of-tag-wikis-with-content-copied)
- [How should I report plagiarized tag wikis?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289246/how-should-i-report-plagiarized-tag-wikis)
- [Plagiarism from Wikipedia survived for 3 years in the C# tag excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302436/plagiarism-from-wikipedia-survived-for-3-years-in-the-c-tag-excerpt)
- etc.

What is a good way to deal with this, since the current system does not work well enough? People put only minimal effort into reviewing these, so I don't think we can really expect the reviewers to change.

Would SO entertain an idea like this: When an edit is submitted, automate a google search for that text. Display some text similarity score (e.g., levenstein, cosine-similarity) to the reviewers. So when I get a tag review, the page will have the approve/reject buttons and an orange box that says "heads up, check that this isn't copied and unattributed."

Comment: I've wished for something like this before too (and not just for tag wikis). But isn't automated google searching a ToS violation?

Comment: I have no idea about google's TOS. That would be a wrench in the plan.

Comment: @Shog9 A plagiarism checker would do the job fine - I'm fairly sure there's a few APIs for those out there.

Comment: Worth noting: the user who suggested the edit has been on the site for six days, and the tag wiki and tag wiki suggested edits are his only activity.  It's highly likely that this is an employee of Sabre.  See http://www.linkedin.com/in/jmacagno

Comment: See also / related: [The tag wiki suggested edit review mechanism encourages low quality wiki content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254135/168868)

Comment: That one *should* have been rejected by all reviewers for **using first-person to talk about the product**.  It's supposed to be a neutral description.  No google searching necessary to spot that one.  I guess we need some honeypot entries for this type of inappropriate language.