# Is a link-only description valid for a tag wiki edit?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I've just done my daily reviews for the Suggested Edits queue, and sometimes I like to go back over my reviews to see how other people have voted and to see if I'm acting in-line.

[This tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6762994) however, I disagreed quite strongly with the other voters because it contains *just* a link.

Is a link-only description valid for a tag wiki edit?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. That edit should have been rejected flat-out. Posting one link as a tag wiki is about the most useless thing anyone could do with a tag wiki.

Comment: I've just been reading [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254135/the-tag-wiki-suggested-edit-review-mechanism-encourages-low-quality-wiki-content?rq=1). It seems there is an underlying problem.

Comment: Those reviewers may need some revision