# Should we approve a tag wiki suggestion which only consists of a name and a link?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Yesterday, when reviewing suggested edits, I encountered this tag wiki proposal: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31904657

It creates a tag wiki for a new tag [opensees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensees), which at this time has only one closed question. The suggestion consists of the framework name and a link to its official website.

Since the suggestion looked rather low-effort and little useful, but wasn't *bad* either, I wasn't exactly sure what to do with that, so I brought it up in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54678509). However, after some discussion, we didn't have any strong feelings in either direction:

- On the one hand, something is better than nothing - the name and the link give the tag context, and may help curators determine whether the tag is relevant for a post.
- On the other hand, there are [guidelines for writing tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one). For example, the wiki could have contained a short description what OpenSees *is* (i.e., an SDK), and indicate why it is relevant to our site.

Note that it is not [link-only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283759/is-a-link-only-description-valid-for-a-tag-wiki-edit), which would have been a clear reason for rejection.

The edit has been approved in the meantime (and I'm fine with that outcome, personally), but it would be great if we could have guidance for future similar cases. Of course I could always skip, but at some point someone has to make a decision.

My questions are:

1. Do the guidelines imply some "minimum requirement" for a tag wiki suggestion, i.e., information that it *has* to contain?
2. Consequently, should we approve suggestions like the one linked above?

Comment: Also lacks usage guidance. That ain't a good tag wiki, and it shouldn't have been approved

Comment: @Zoe Usage guidance goes in the excerpt; this was a wiki, not an excerpt.  I approved it because it clarified an unclear the meaning of a not-immediately-clear acronym, and provided a link where someone could find out more.

Comment: I see I got my excepts and wikis mixed up (thanks to the UI that makes it so clear which one it is). In either case, it doesn't meet any of the other tag wiki requirements, as OP outlined in the second bullet.

Comment: Frankly, you are not the only reviewer that has trouble identifying what to do with such wiki entries. I tend to skip them and defer to others unless I am an SME and can assess what *must*'ve been specified in the wiki to be useful. In all honesty, I'd be inclined to reject if I had a power to do so unilaterally as such edits do not, in fact, meet the guidelines for good tag wikis.

Comment: IMO, it depends. For new tags which only exist on a question or two, then if the tag is already unambiguous like this one is, I see no benefit whatsoever in this tag wiki. For older tags on more questions which have somehow avoided getting a wiki, then again it depends on whether or not the wiki that has been suggested appears to be relevant to the vast majority of the questions in the tag, not just that it makes sense for the given tag name. It's not a simple yes/no.

Answer (score 7):

Let me see if I can step back from the approval debate in the comments and talk about the bigger picture for a second.

We want to be careful creating new tags because cleaning up bad tags (which can lead to bad questions) is a major task [with a really long list of backlogged tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+is%3Aq). So obviously we try to be on guard for folks rolling up new tags without good reason. Adding excerpts and wikis make tags more "real".

The other end of this is that we do sometimes want to know *something* about the tag, even if that information is minimal. This particular edit makes for a barely passable **wiki** (seriously, if you're reading this, please add more meat to it than the edit in the question proffered), but an unacceptably insufficient **excerpt** ("[tag] is about Tag <link here>" is a stock rejection reason). Alas, the system doesn't do a good job at telling reviewers which is which, hence the mod confusion (it trips me up sometimes as well).

And, of course, [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) are never acceptable.

## TL;DR

We would prefer a tag have a rich and robust **wiki entry**, but if a link is all someone can manage for a new tag (again, not acceptable for an **excerpt**), we shouldn't reject it.

Answer (score -1):

I was one of the reviewers who approved, the tag wiki was **borderline** and under normal circumstances I would be 80% inclined to reject the edit.

**BUT**, it's a scientific library that's about earthquake research from a reputable institution with only [20 text hits in search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opensees)... From experience I know what it's like doing research in **niche** scientific areas and not finding enough resources where fellow programmers are solving the same concrete problems. So, with 20 hits, approving an on-topic, clearly delimited, tag that pertains to very specific programming problems seems to be what this site is all about. I'd rather contribute towards helping such a niche tag gain traction and seeing where it goes than leaving it without  a tag.

That's a reviewers *"judgement call"* and as I explained above I didn't take it lightly.

Comment: "20 text hits in search", only if you are self-abusive. No one should use the site search unless they know what they are looking for. It has 400k results on the internet and if you search for "opensees documentation" you can find the documentation already. So, I don't think this qualify as "niche scientific area" that is hard to find info about, to be exception.

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, I know how your tag arguments go and the official BB of the library is where most questions seem to get asked - it doesn't have that many questions overall and the hits your refer are mostly literature publications not programming Q&A. However, as is the case with many libraries and tools, a developer can choose to ask on SO and there's no rule against that. (In many tags that kind of cross-posting gives good results.)

Comment: @Braiam your objection is also speculative not prudential, you don't know anything about the library so your guess is likely no better than mine. I didn't say the library is niche - read more carefully.

Comment: There's no rule against that, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that your argument is deeply flawed and do not represent the common user of Stack Overflow or any user at all. When was the last time you found a web site and the first thing you did was use their built-in search? Mine was never.

Comment: @Braiam well, whatever the site I'm on among my first priorities is learning to use the internal search. Google doesn't solve everything.