# Bad mass tag wiki updates

Tags: discussion, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, plagiarism

A [certain user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) is making a large number of tag wiki edits, many of which are harmful or otherwise improper:

- [Turning a correctly-formed sentence into two fragments with the comment "improved grammar"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4974575)
- [Making an accurate sentence completely inaccurate with the comment "improved grammar"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4975166)
- [Another inaccuracy as "improved grammer"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4980450) (sic)
- Plagiarism - [DocuShare tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4965026) (copied from http://dmimps.com/document-management/)
- Plagiarism 2 - [Meekro tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4963113) (copied from http://www.meekro.com/)
- Plagiarism 3 - [Meekro tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4963112) (copied from http://www.meekro.com/pdo.php)
- Plagiarism 4 - [jsDelivr tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4965043) (copied from http://www.jsdelivr.com/about.php)

These are just ones that were approved by reviewers. There were many more rejected by reviewers.

Can we do something about this?

Comment: I kind of wish that tag wikis had a rollback feature.  I've edited out the C++ tag excerpt; that shouldn't have made it past the review queue with those guys [not having](http://stackoverflow.com/users/768795/thomas-w?tab=tags) [a strong showing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/159769/x2?tab=tags&sort=name) [in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/users/117259/jakegould?tab=tags).

Comment: Oh, he is [earning reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch?tab=reputation) by _suggesting_ edits to tag wikis.  Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250613/mass-updating-of-tag-wikis-with-content-copied

Comment: See what sort of edits were done by the user in the referenced question.  He stopped when he stopped getting the rep by suggesting edits having hit the limit.  I wish that the mods could step in earlier.

Comment: Mods *can* step in. So can community members. At least to some extent. Leave the guy a comment, point out his mistakes, and ask him to stop. Unless he's a real incorrigible bastard, he'll probably listen; we've had success with that before. The ***real*** problem here are the reviewers...

Comment: Member for 6 months and has 20k rep? Jesus...

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, the real problem are reviewers.  But the problem exists elsewhere too -- that such reviewers continue to do so.  People want to propose edits for rep, but there are badges for reviewing too and there are many out there who want to _earn_ those real fast.

Comment: How is that "elsewhere", @devnull? That's exactly the *same* place: reviewers approving bad edits. The pursuit of badges isn't a sufficient explanation for the phenomenon; you get badges for *rejecting* edits, too.

Comment: @CodyGray (1) By "elsewhere", I mean that such users ought to be given a _break_ from reviewing.  Look at the question I linked above.  The user in question was on a massive wiki editing spree and made terrible suggestions that were approved.  Even after the meta post, the user wasn't _given a break from editing_.  The user _gave up_ after hitting the rep limit by suggesting edits.  (2) Robos usually approve, not reject.

Comment: With another 107 reputation, that user won't require that these edits be approved any more - that's just scary (although he might stop given that he won't be getting reputation any more), and we should probably check for rubbish edited into posts by this user as well.

Comment: He just did the same thing to the C tag wiki excerpt that he did to C++. C is not a subset of C++; they are different languages (as the excerpt *had* said).

Comment: I sent him a message.  Note that you can easily fix the plagiarism problems by adding a link to the source.

Comment: @RobertHarvey None of the source pages indicate a permissive license for their content, so this may be copyright infringement that can't be fixed with a citation.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: We're giving all of those pages free promotion.  Do you really think they're going to care about that little bit of text?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use

Comment: @RobertHarvey StackExchange Inc. does **profit** from the use of the copied text (serving ads), so that may diminish the fair use argument.