# Restrict reviews of tag wikis/excerpts to those who've spent time in that tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258281/1079354) got me thinking...three users were able to approve edits to a tag wiki that they don't have any sort of showing in.

[image][image][image]

(I'm sure that third user had a momentary blip, and that his C++ tag score is so innumerable that it can't appear in sorted order.)

The concern that I have with this is that it leads to ***very*** poor reviews of the tag blurb and content, and could lead to misleading or damaging information being spread through those.

What I'm proposing here is hopefully a simple system to prevent bad edits to tag wikis.

**Any user** that is **reviewing** any given tag must meet this criteria:

- If there  is **at least one gold badge user** in it:

  - One must have a bronze badge in the tag  - this is enough to establish familiarity with the content material to know what's good, bad, and/or ugly.
- Otherwise, the user must meet one of these two criteria:

  - **Be a trusted user** (been around the system long enough that the system and community likely trust you to not mess things up too badly), or
  - **Be one of the top 20 users in the tag**.

Suggesting edits to the tag wiki and excerpt will **remain the same.**

A [cursory glance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) at the bronze badges page suggests that there's less than 3K users in any one tag; this reduces the surface area of potentially poor edits.  This *may* also introduce the scenario in which there aren't enough people reviewing the less boisterous tags, but the total amount of trusted users in the system (ballpark about 1.8-2K) *should* cover that.

Of course, this is open to suggestion.  Hopefully this curbs bad edits to tag wikis.

Comment: really good idea .. and    trusted user with bronze badge and other user with silver badge  will also work

Comment: Both demographics are so small though; I would imagine that only a bronze badge would suffice.  There are few enough people with the bronze badge in a tag, that I'd wager trying it with those people alone would be a good idea.

Comment: What about new tags? Since people stint have a bronze badge in that goes would that wiki be updated?

Comment: +1. I have been talking about this for a while, but some people seemed objective to it. I am happy to see you bringing this up.

Comment: That could be a problem for low-usage tags. For example, I've had the gold badge for [tag:ssl] for a while, yet I only got the (only) [tag:tls] bronze tag a couple of days ago. (It's a particular case I suppose, because they were made synonyms about a year ago anyway.)

Comment: @Howlin.Good Point.So to remove those problem why dont we have some thing called Friendly tag.For example when it comes to php in most cases it is tagged with mysql or laravel etc.So why cant we create something like that and allow edit approvals for those whose have scored on tag and friendly tags ?

Comment: Who decides what these "friendly tags" are, @krishna? And who maintains that list?

Comment: @CodyGray For existing tag we can do same like tag synonyms. we will ask users using those tag to propose friendly tags and for new tags let moderators or others with bronze badge of the proposed tag can  propose and peoples using those tags can vote for approval

Comment: I don't have time to read all the comments, so I apologize if this has been mentioned already. I think we should consider extending the idea that only badge holders (say silver or gold) should take certain kinds of actions on questions with those tags should be extended to other actions, such as closing questions. I've seen users with little or no score in [tag:git] close a perfectly legitimate Git question as "belonging on [su]". Of course, we'd have to make special rules for tags without a lot of gold-badge users.

Comment: @Cupcake:  The special rule that Ben Voigt proposed was recently incorporated into the suggestion.  Would that appease/suffice as a "special rule"?  The only real case I didn't consider was a tag without many gold badge users, which is far more common than I had believed when I wrote this at quarter-til-1AM.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to simplify these rules and remove gold badge condition. Just allowing trusted users, users with bronze badge, and top 20 users on specific tag to accept edits.

Comment: @doc:  Not so sure about that; the gold badge restriction was there to likely prevent bogus reviews by those who weren't familiar.  Ben Voight's suggestion below isn't that bad; it's workable and offers a happy medium in my mind.

Comment: @Makoto it would be best if edit was visible for users familiar with a tag (bronze badge+) for let's say first 48 hours. Only if there's no reaction make it visible to high rep users. This guarantees that edits won't be pending forever.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I propose a simple additional rule so that it doesn't adversely affect low-volume tags:

- If any gold badge has been issued in the tag, all edits must originate from or be approved by at least one user with either

  - bronze badge in the tag, or
  - listed in all-time top 20 (?) users in the tag

There might be a need for suggested wiki edits to actually trigger notifications to gold badge holders in the tag (maybe only for tags where the number of gold badge holders is not more than a dozen), in case they don't frequently check the review tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect that wouldn't be enough, because you often have a single gold badge in small tags.  [tag:sas] for example, I have a gold badge - and there aren't even enough other users with remotely high rep to close questions most of the time.  While there are several bronze badge users, they're really not on often enough nor do I suspect they review all that often.

Comment: @Joe: We're talking about wiki edits... you don't need a large number of users, at all, for those.

Comment: You need people reviewing. Small tags may not have people reviewing even if they have badges ...

Comment: +1 In small tags badges are acquired mostly by perseverance because both votes and questions are rare, for example in [tag:sparql] I am the only one with a bronze/silver badge (there are no golds) yet the [top sparql users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sparql/topusers) includes people I would consider world leaders in the tag such as the authors of the W3C specification and of the leading reference implementations

Comment: So perhaps the modification should be "If any gold badge has been issued in the tag, no edits or reviews by users who don't hold a bronze badge or are in the all time top users"

Comment: Ok, top users *in the tag* I can agree with.  I don't like the question's proposal to allow "trusted users", which sounds purely rep-based, to make edits.

Comment: @Joe: Also, if you're the gold badge holder, and no one else has even a bronze badge, you're clearly pretty active and willing to contribute; I think SO should lean heavily toward giving you (effective) ownership of the tag wiki.

Comment: One person can't approve a tag or wiki edit (unless they're a mod I guess).  And I don't necessarily review all that much either... it is easy enough for me to identify spurious edits and fix them.

Comment: Without trusted users being able to approve, there's _zero_ chance this would fly - I'd certainly heavily oppose it.  You've got to trust people at some point to review things; no other review task requires tag familiarity, for good reason.  I've reviewed dozens of tag/wiki edits, almost never in tags i'm familiar with, and I'm almost always able to reasonably adjudicate them.  The ones I don't feel comfortable with I skip - same as everyone should.

Comment: Adding in "top 20 users" or whatever isn't helpful either - in many small tags the top users have a few hundred rep.  They can't access review tools.

Comment: @Joe: That's why tags with no gold badge are exempted.

Comment: Sure, except again, in my tag I do have a gold badge.  There are 12 users with bronze or above badge in [tag:sas], 7 of which have some reasonable activity level lately.  Other than me, one of them has completed  even a single review task in the last three months, and that was on a single day performing a few dozen reviews (and was all of his reviews, ever).  In your example, _no_ [tag:sas] wiki edit would ever be approved.

Comment: @Joe: I think Ben is trying to write about common tags, not corner cases. Let us fix the majority first, and then we can think about the corner cases. I personally support this, +1, not that it matters much as the decisions are not taken democratically anyway.

Comment: @Joe: So let high-rep uses count for 2 of the 3 required accept votes.  But don't allow an accept that no user active on that tag has looked at.  Use notifications to get the attention of one of those users, if necessary.

Comment: @Joe: The second thing is that I'm not convinced that `sas` wiki *suggested* edits never being approved is really a problem.  The 20 most involved users in the tag would all have the ability to edit the wiki, no approval required.

Comment: Often people not involved with the tag don't understand that information can prevent X-Y questions.  This maybe good to get content approved as well.  There is also the concept of *related tags*, that maybe beneficial.  For instance, [tag:trust-zone], [tag:cortex-a], [tag:cortex-a8] are all derivatives of [tag:arm].  For instance with the tag [tag:sas], it seems that [tag:sql] people may be competent.  Remember, if none of the criteria exist we default to the normal use case.

Comment: I like these suggestions, but I feel that gold is a bit too ambitious (as not all tags have a gold badge user in them).  Perhaps silver?  I'll be revising my proposal accordingly to see what else could come of this.

Comment: @Makoto:the ideas is that tags without a gold badge user aren't high volume enough to review themselves, and will still need to have the community at large do so.

Comment: @Makoto: You're welcome to take it as-is, but the comments have suggested that some variation might be needed.

Answer (score 6):

Wiki/tag excerpt reviews serve two major purposes:

- Making sure the edit is not against policy (mostly, making sure it's not a copy/paste of copyrighted material)
- Making sure the edit is consistent with the purpose of the tag.

The former can be done by anyone, tag specific knowledge is irrelevant.  The latter can be done better by tag readers.

If all tags had large readerships, I think I'd support this wholeheartedly.  However, there are many tags with very few readers - newer tags, or just smaller tags.  While your suggestion does include Trusted Users, I think that the downside is pretty close to equal to the upside here.

The upside is that you avoid type 2 mistakes - wiki/tag edits that don't actually improve the wiki/tag. However, those are **easy to correct**, particularly in the larger tags: tag readers will see the tag wiki is not correct and roll back the changes.

However, the downside is much slower approval of wiki/tag edits on smaller tags.  This isn't necessarily a huge downside, but given how easy to correct the mistakes the upside is fixing, I'm not convinced this isn't enough to justify not doing it.

Comment: Perhaps there need to be two types of review on wiki and excerpt edits?  One for each of your bullets.  The first needs reviews with high audit pass rates, and is skipped if the original editor qualifies to review.  The second needs reviewers with bronze badge or top-25 user in the tag, and is skipped if the original editor qualifies.  Requiring even one review of *each* type could be far more effective than today's 3 approvals by high-rep users today who may know nothing about the tag usage.