# Manually restrict review topics

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, review-queues

I am relatively new to the review task, but am keen to contribute.

My knowledge is limited to several topics (`perl`, `regex` and some `R`), and I wouldn't feel comfortable reviewing items outside of these areas.

Would it be possible to either

- Filter the review items by tag (e.g. `perl`), OR
- Restrict the displayed review items to topics within your knowledge area (which could become less restricted over time)

This would make contributing much easier for those, like me, with a limited breadth of expertise.

A similar point was raised in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258285/restrict-reviews-of-tag-wikis-excerpts-to-those-whove-spent-time-in-that-tag), but what I'm proposing is the ability to **manually** control restricted review rights (as opposed to it being decided based on your tag rep/ number of badges).

Comment: Many (most? All?) of the review tasks neither expect nor require you to have specific domain expertise; if you find one that you think *does*, and you don't have it, Skip.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, You can filter by tag all review queue except Triage(I think).

Review -> Any Review queue Except Triage , Then on top of the page, You see one Filter link, where you can add Tag you want to filter out.

[image]

Comment: Or have a direct link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=regex;r;perl

Comment: @rene:- if you add one more tag in your given link,  http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=regex;r;perl;c , then all filters are gone. I know only three tags are allowed, but it should take first three instead of clear all filter

Comment: Yeah, I'm not even sure if that trick is officially supported (as in part of the public contract). I believe it was added when the close vote queue was fuzzied to give users quick access to some interesting tags. So don't expect bug-reports to be handled ;)

Comment: @rene this is [official announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209777/165773). Per my reading, it is a bit too... _fuzzy_ to be considered as solid specification and to justify bug reports