# Tag wiki suggested edits and robo-reviewers

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was wondering what could be a better way to prevent tag wikis with [useless](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5201662) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5201064).  The reason is that much of such edits are [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5200052) [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5200504).

I'm often led to wonder if there exists a secret mechanism that awards robos to approve every edit that comes in their way.  Even if there isn't one, it appears that there is little or no reason for the reviewers to pause for a moment before hitting either "Approve" or "Reject".  The common choice seems to be "Approve", though.

Rep based review system, i.e. increasing the rep required for reviewing tag wiki edits, isn't likely to help either.  Robos come in all shapes, sizes, reputation and color.  Is there a mechanism by which it might be easier to let such reviewers have a good break?

There is no [plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250613/mass-updating-of-tag-wikis-with-content-copied) in the examples above, but the edits don't seem to be in line with the [tag wiki guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

Alternatively, can we devise a mechanism to make the reviewers more familiar with the tag wiki guidelines?

Comment: I find the grammar editing examples you've picked to be harmless enough, why should those not have been approved?

Comment: I will find a few bad tag edits for you, your examples are not good.

Comment: Checke [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22493615/revisions) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12828978/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can draw moderator attention to reviewers, so the moderators can give such robo-reviewers a break with a manual review ban. Reserve this for blatant robo-reviewers (where you've found that they have approved multiple bad suggested edits).

For tag wiki edits, that is a little harder. You'll have to find a post by the user and flag that instead. Use `other`, explain with a link to the review and any others you find suspicious.

**However**, many the examples you have picked are not obviously *wrong*. I don't quite see why those reviewers should be singled out in *those* cases.

Only one could qualify for [Too Minor](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5201064), adding in the header 'screenshot' is not all that helpful there.

The `pascalscript` wiki excerpt edit appears to plagiarising the [project homepage](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx), but with just one slightly altered sentence that's minor enough. The excerpt is within guidelines; it explains better than the previous version as to what the tag is about. The excerpts in the Tag Wiki guidelines blog post certainly use similar language (description of the concept, not how to use the tag).